# Jquery Slider animation does not work in ember.js when the page is visited

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a [Jquery Revolution Slider](http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/revolution_wp/) working alongide ember.js . The Jquery Revolution slider is implemented on the index page. However when I navigate to the default route using ember, the slider is not animated. the slider only animates when the page is refreshed manually.

is there a way to refresh the page in ember.js ?

Here is the page : http://softkrafts.com/granite/granite/

when the page is loaded the animation works. 
Steps to reproduce the issue.

1. Click on the about link - the about route works (the big red about us text is displayed)
   .
2. Now click on the home nav link . notice that the animation does not work. However when you refresh the page everything starts to work.

Comment: You should show some code. It is likely that it works when it is implemented properly.

Comment: did you found the answer for this? as I am too getting this error :(

Comment: nope.. i could not find a solution for this.. i had to remove revolution slider in the production version.